# Linux tr to convert vertical text to horizontal

Tags: linux, tr

I've been reading about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791042/convert-vertical-text-into-horizontal-in-shell
and wondering if `tr` alone can be used to convert vertical text to horizontal.

```
user@linux:~$ seq 3
1
2
3
user@linux:~$
```

I've tried the following solution, it works but not perfect.

```
user@linux:~$ seq 3 | tr -d '\n'
123user@linux:~$ 
user@linux:~$
```

Would it be possible to used `tr` alone to produce output like this?

**Desired Output**

```
user@linux:~$ seq 3 | tr command here
123
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: `tr -d '\n'` is finr for all  piped and file-to-file operations. Don't be fooled by the tty output.

Comment: @Fiximan no it's not. Otherwise the following would work as expected: `seq 3 | tr -d '\n' | cat`. Notice the pipe to `cat` here, which didn't add the newline as the OP wanted (and which POSIX text files are required to have).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose whatever works for you.

```
$ seq 3 | paste -s -d ''
123
$ seq 3 | tr -d '\n';echo
123
$ seq 3 | awk 1 ORS='';echo
123
```

Comment: Note that `paste -s -d ''` is not portable nor POSIX. The portable equivalent would be `paste -sd '\0' -`

Answer (score 4):

```
$ seq -s '' 3
123
```

This instructs `seq` to use the empty string as separator for the numbers (rather than the default newline character).

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about this. What if the vertical text is saved in a file instead of `seq 3`?

Comment: @Sabrina Then you would use any of the alternatives in asktyagi's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 seq 3 | paste -s -d ''
 123
```

- -d, delimiters as null
- -s, print in serial instead of in parallel

Comment: So it's not possible to use `tr` alone to solve this?

Comment: Note that `paste -s -d ''` is not portable nor POSIX. The portable equivalent would be `paste -sd '\0' -`

Answer (score 2):

You could use *two* `tr` commands and some shell features (a shell built-in, and a here-string or here-doc):

```
seq 3 | (tr -d '\n'; tr -s '\n' <<< "")

seq 3 | (tr -d '\n'; tr -s '\n' << EOF

EOF
)
```

Comment: You might as well use `tr -s '\n' <<< ''` or `tr x y <<< ''`

Comment: Good point, Stéphane; I got stuck initially trying to convert /dev/null or /dev/zero; I'll simplify it with your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be

```
echo $(seq 3 | tr -d '\n')
```

As you are removing all newlines with switch `-d '\n'` you have to add the last one again with some sort of trick.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below 2 methods

First method

command:

```
seq 3| perl -pne "s/\n//g"
```

output
123

Second(Python)

## !/usr/bin/python

```
import re
z=[]
import subprocess
k=open('o','r')
for i in k:
    z.append(i.strip())

print "".join(z)
```

Note: Here o is the filename

output

```
@host-1-49 ~]# python o.py 
123
```